# Best pythonic way of mapping a specific function with multiple arguments

Tags: python, for-loop, map-function

Say I have a method:

```
def add_force_coupling(g1, g2, name):
    print {(g1,g2): name}
```

then the code:

```
l = 3
for g1 in range(l):
    for g2 in range(l):
      name = 'G' + str(g1) + str(g2)
      add_force_coupling(g1, g2, name)
```

produces the result:

```
{(0, 0): 'G00'}, {(0, 1): 'G01'}, {(0, 2): 'G02'}, {(1, 0): 'G10'}, ..., {(2, 2): 'G22'}
```

Now I want to make this more pythonic by using the `map()` function. So far I have got:

```
list1 = sorted(l*range(l))
list2 = l*range(l)
list3 = ["".join(values) for values in zip(l*l*'G',list(map(str,l1)),list(map(str,l2)))]
map( add_force_coupling, list1, list2, list3 )
```

which does exactly what I want but is uglier than the standard double loop since the int list need to be converted to `str` in `list3`. Also it is quite difficult to understand what is going on. Is there any better pythonic way of rewriting the double loop with a `map()`, `zip()` or otherwise?

Note: changing the method is not an option

Comment: Is there a reason you believe using a one-liner will be more pythonic?

Comment: Why all the separate dictionaries. Did you mean to produce **one** dictionary with l squared keys instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters why use a dictionary at all this seems much better suited to a 2d list ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: True enough.

Comment: @SethMMorton: Maybe pythonic is not the correct description in this case; i prefer code to be more concise.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The function produces one dict in the actual code. Also it is more complicated than the print statement; it was just added to show what output is desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `map()`. Use a list comprehension and [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

[{(i, j): 'G{}{}'.format(i, j)} for i, j in product(range(l), repeat=2)]
```

or using your function for the left-hand expression:

```
[add_force_coupling(i, j, 'G{}{}'.format(i, j))
 for i, j in product(range(l), repeat=2)]
```

It does strike me that you are looking to build *one* dictionary here; a dict comprehension could do that:

```
{(i, j): 'G{}{}'.format(i, j) for i, j in product(range(l), repeat=2)}
```

Here you can address each item with `result[i, j]`.

but given the indices, a nested list would be a more efficient storage mechanism for the data:

```
[['G{}{}'.format(i, j) for j in range(l)] for i in range(l)]
```

and address results with

```
result[i][j]
```

Comment: your answers are always so thorough +1

Comment: I dont think this is what i want although i like the use of format(). The reason i wanted to use map() is to call the function add_force_coupling with the lists of arguments. In the function the arguments are used to set keys and values of one single dictionary. Here you have basically bypassed the function by setting a dict in a list comprehension but i need the function since it is slightly more complicated than setting a dict.

Comment: @nlooije: I added in an example using the function. `map()` is not the right tool here.

Answer (score 1):

dont use a map or a dictionary this is naturally represented as a 2d list

```
data = [['G{0}{1}'.format(j,i) for i in range(l)] for j in range(l)]

data[0][0]
print data[0][1] 
...
```

hmm the *note* at the end makes me thing that this is perhaps not what OP needs ... but it is still a more appropriate solution to the general problem here (at least imho)

Comment: you are right, this isnt what i need :P. i need to call the function for all the different lists. This bypasses the function by setting the dict directly (see other comment)